# How to start with ngx-graph for Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript, graph, diagram

I am trying to use ngx-graph for Angular 7 to create a network diagram. But since the documentation is not very good and the demo is too much for a beginner I would appreciate any help of how to begin with ngx-graph. Maybe with a small example with 2 nodes and 1 link between them.

I hope somebody can help me.

Thank you :)

Comment: Have a look at:https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts and https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a documentation for it: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph

First, install the package with D3 dependency:

```
npm install @swimlane/ngx-graph --save
npm install d3 --save
```

And import `NgxGraphModule` to your module (`app.module.ts`).

After, you can use `<ngx-graph></ngx-graph>` component in your components (HTML), and data in the component logic. The documentation explains, and has an example how to set data and required properties.

[Demo](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/)

[Demo-Code](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph/tree/master/demo)

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible, that you could post a small example? Just that I can get a feeling for it. I'm not getting smarter with the example in the documentation.

Comment: @Michael I added links for demo code and demo itself. Check the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

The ngx-graph documentation is a must-read to have a better understanding before you do something more with ngx-graph and want to customize according to your needs.
https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph

Here is my customized code to start with not only basics but very important features like adding, connecting and deleting nodes using GUI.
https://github.com/rat17sri/ngx-graph-angular

Demo: https://rat17sri.github.io/ngx-graph-angular/